# Remove Similar Name Files Based on Epoch Identifier

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to remove extra files based on the epoch identifier. When I'm pulling down a bunch of reports, there are some reports with the same name but have a unique epoch. I'd like to remove the earlier one and just keep the latest report for all the files in the directory.

ex)

1. file1-1498592006.csv
2. file1-1498592004.csv

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would imagine you'd be employing a regular expression, correct?

Comment: Regex is overkill here. An rsplit on `-` is enough.

Comment: @Coldspeed yeah you're right, I misunderstood the goal here when I first read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of filenames you've already seen with a `set`. Any duplicates can then be deleted off.

```
seen = set()
for file in sorted(os.listdir('/path/to/your/reports'), reverse=True):
    filename = file.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
    if filename not in seen:
        seen.add(filename)
    else:
        os.unlink(file)
```

You can use `os.unlink` to delete the extras.

Thanks to @Błotosmętek for this: You'll sort the files in descending order to guarantee that only the most recent report is retained.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if there was only one common file name i.e. a directory containing all "file1" 's? There would have to be some iteration through all of the common file names I think, unless I'm missing the point here

Comment: Not so. Each time you happen upon a _new_ filename, say file-2, that file is retained and the entry added to the set. Future file-2's will be determined to already exist in the set and will be deleted.

Comment: First sort the filenames descendingly by the "epoch" part, that'll guarantee that the file you keep is the newest.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Great catch! Thanks a bunch, I've edited my post.